# TextMate source.java comment block folding

Tags: java, textmate, textmatebundles

How do I modify the java language definition bundle foldingStartMarker and foldingStopMarker entries to allow for folding of these types of comment blocks?

This is the comment style:

```
/**
 * This is a comment...
 * Yet another comment...
 */
```

I've tried this:

```
foldingStartMarker = '(\{\s*(//.*)?$|^\s*// \{\{\{|^\s*\/\*\*)';
foldingStopMarker = '^\s*(\}|// \}\}\}$|\*\/)';
```

I get the first match for '/**' characters, but I can't get it to find the StopMarker '*/'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (in Javascript language):

```
foldingStartMarker = '^\s*\/\*';
foldingStopMarker = '\s*\*\/$';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal but I found that if you end your comment with **/ instead of */ in a C++ source file, it recognizes them for folding.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here (custom language, but same comment block style). It seems that the `foldingStopMarker` never works on lines starting with a whitespace.

I tried many combinations and whenever the line does start with a whitespace, I was unable to build a `foldingStopMarker` regex that would match it, independent of the other characters in that line.

Seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot be done at the moment. Documented textmate behaviour, folding start and stop must have exactly the same indention level. Use the **/ workaround.